# How to find users by custom attribute in python-intercom

Tags: python, intercom

I am going to use python-intercom find_all method to find all users which has custom attribute ( "Agency Status") value is Suspended, but couldn't find any way to handle this issue.

What I wrote is below, but it returns all users instead of suspended users.

```
suspenso_users = intercom_client.users.find_all(custom_attributes={"Agency Status":"Suspensed"})
```

If there is anyone who has experience of custom attribute based filtering, please help me.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow.  Please have a look at the reference, [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [mcve] to work with.

Answer (score 0):

The ability to find users that contain a specific value for a custom attribute isn't currently available. You would have iterate through your user list and search for users with the specific attribute you're looking for. The only parameters you can use the find call for are for the `id`, `user_id` and `email` fields. This is subject to change in the future though.

That said, something to consider when architecting your model is that you can [search for users by `tag` or `segment`](https://developers.intercom.com/intercom-api-reference/reference#list-by-tag-segment-company). So, for example, you can [tag these users programmatically based off of webhooks](https://developers.intercom.com/intercom-api-reference/reference#subscription-model), then [search for them using the tag(s)](https://developers.intercom.com/intercom-api-reference/reference#list-by-tag-segment-company).